# What can I do if my website don't need menu or sidebar?

Tags: website-design, gui-design, material-design, ux-designer

I want to show the user cards. Between 1 to 100 cards. The user can open existing card, or create new card. In the new card he can type a text, and click save.
That's all.

How to design it? I think is ugly, A blank white page, that shown 10 text cards.
What can I add to the page? I don't need menu (just login/logout), and nothing more.

*(I'm walking the Material directions...)*

[image]
[image]

Comment: There is no correct answer to this. It's going to depend on your specific project requirements.

Answer (score 3):

Why would it be ugly? It's quite a good opportunity to use a minimalist design.

Start by doing a first wireframe, and look for minimalist design examples and references that would fit users' expectations. You will find out a rather innovative and nice design ;)

Post back your wireframe over here if you feel stuck.

Comment: Screenshots attached. Something missing in my design

Comment: Thanks :) J4G is right: it's better to start by listing the required functionalities from the typical use cases before doing the wireframe (I was may be influenced by your graphic-design question ;) ).

Comment: Then, for the first wireframe, I'm wondering if the users are guided enough. If I'm completely new to the service, will I understand the purpose of it (within a few seconds), and then how to use it? Also, you may want to inject a little bit of brand identity with a name or something else. And finally, if your design is minimalist, it should be pixel-perfect. I'm afraid that the plus-button would break the consistency of your grid-design. Why not add a special card which would be used to add a new card?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Yako, simple is best and there's no need to over complicate here!  Have you considered what additional functionality needs to be included, and what use cases and user journeys should be catered for?

For example, how can a user's task of finding one specific card be made to be as simple as possible?  Are there categories/tags that you can use, so that a user can click on a tag and only be shown cards that correspond?

If all functionalities and experiences cater for the reason the user has come to this page/site then you can't go wrong.  Useful is more important than beautiful, but there's no reason why it can't be both!